# How can I do decimal to hex.?

Tags: c

I want to write a decimal and see hex.
I wrote some codes but it didnt work.What is wrong?
thanks.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()

{
    int l(int);
    int k(int);
    char cha;

    int x, y = 0, z = 18, a = 0, b = 0, c = 0, d = 0;

    scanf("%d %c", &x, &cha); //x a decimal number//
                              //I // 

    if (x>0 && x <= 65535) // kalsın //
    {

        if (cha == 'h' || cha == 'H')

        {
            y = x;


            for (z = 18; z >= 16; c++)
            {
                z = x / 16;
                x = x / 16;

            }
            z = k(z); /* this is a function for finding that what is in hex.*/
            d = c;
            for (a = 0; a != c; a++)
            {

                c = d;
                for (; c >= a; c--)
                {
                    b = y % 16;
                    y = y / 16;
                }
                b = k(b);    /* find what is */
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}




int k(int d)
{
    int e = d;
    if (e == 10) printf("A");
    else if (e == 11) printf("B");
    else if (e == 12) printf("C");
    else if (e == 13) printf("D");
    else if (e == 14) printf("E");
    else if (e == 15) printf("F");
    else if (e<10) printf("%d", e);

    return e;
}
```

what is the problem in this code.write 162 h
and I see 0000000...
I can use only loops (control) and simple functions

Comment: OMG just print it with `printf( "%X", number)`

Comment: You definitely want to learn how to use a debugger, to trace your code step by step and while doing so inspect the values of all relevant variables.

Comment: Use proper names and (re-)read a good C book. There are quite some things you do wrong.

Comment: The `k` function (what an intuitive name BTW) ist just horrible and can be rewritten in 2 lines.

Comment: @Slava he want's to to this as an exercice.

Comment: HInt: 'const char* hexlat="0123456789ABCDEF";', index it with nibbles..

Answer (score 1):

> How can I do decimal to hex.?

Do

```
int a = 2000;
printf( "%X", a);
```

Output:

> 7D0

In other words: 2000 in hex.

Explaination: Decimal and Hex are just notations (like binary) of the same number. Which notation you want to print is yours to choose.

Comment: He want's to do this as an exercice.

Comment: @MichaelWalz his question specifies writing something as decimal and seeing it in hex. Thats exactly what this does.